# Can't clean assets in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, rake, asset-pipeline

Ok, this is driving me nuts!

I just cloned a rails project that used to have twitter bootstrap styling on it, but it was deleted. When I run the project, I still get the bootstrap styling! I've tried running `rake assets:clean`and get the following output:

```
/Users/ericavirtue/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby /Users/ericavirtue/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin/rake assets:clean:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rm -rf /Users/ericavirtue/Sites/rubyblog/public/assets
```

And my project still has the bootstrap styling on it!

I've removed the bootstrap files from the stylesheets and javascript folders, and removed the reference to bootstrap in application.css.

I've even tried `RAILS_ENV=development rake rails_group=assets assets:clean`

Any ideas? The code can be found here:

[github.com/arelenglish/rubyblog](http://www.github.com/arelenglish.com/rubyblog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check your public folder to make sure that you don't have any precompiled assets in there, and hold shift while clicking refresh to make sure your browser's cache is clear.

Comment: Thanks! It was the cache. Rookie mistake. Ugh. So embarrassing.

Comment: No problem -- Happens to us all.

Answer (score 0):

Use `assets:clobber` to really remove assets. `assets:clean` keeps 2 backups in case older content triggers the old assets being loaded.